# How call a function in a Tkinter menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to call a function clicking on fileMenu 'Action', I was able to call the function (below is just one example) only by entering it in the submenu, is there a way for make it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

def stateMenu():
    fileMenu.entryconfig("Delete", state="disabled") 
    fileMenu.entryconfig("Transfer", state="disabled") 


root = tk.Tk()
menubar = Menu()
fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Action", menu=fileMenu) // I would like call function here
fileMenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=stateMenu, state="normal") // no here
fileMenu.add_command(label="Transfer", command=stateMenu, state="normal") // no here

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function when a menu appears?

Comment: Not when appears but when user click on. 'Action' in in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have to find another way

Answer (score 0):

The only way to call a command from a menubar is by adding the command with `add_command`. Some operating systems allow you to add commands to the root menubar, some don't.

From a usability perspective it's generally considered a bad idea to add commands directly on the menubar. Users expect to see a menu when they click on something on the menubar, and would be surprised if some action immediately happened.

Comment: Complete app is based on a data received through api which should disable and enable those menu items, in this case the user would not know it as it is for personal use. I should be working with a different type of menu, but tkinter doesn't seem to have many alternatives.

Comment: @mustaine: you can create your own toolbar using a frame with buttons and menubuttons if you want something that is different from a traditional menubar.

Comment: Yes, should try this way, even though the default menu was quick. thanks for help